# How can I implement a page slider in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, slide

I am coming from iOS Development and would like to know how I can implement a page slider similar to the one in iOS. I need it to display my home screen for my app. It looks similar to the home screen on iOS where you have all your apps and can slide horizontally through pages.

I would like it to be compatible with at least Android 2.3 (better 2.2 also).

Can someone give me some tips on how to achieve this? Or can someone give me a small example? Learning by seeing how it's actually done is always the best!

Anyway you guys are also the best! Thanks!

Comment: You might wish to explain a bit more what a "page slider similar to the one in iOS" is, as not everybody here will be familiar with iOS. That being said, look at `ViewPager` or `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: Hey, what I am referring to is the iOS home screen (google "iOS Home Screen"). I want to have that UI for Android, compatible with 2.3 (better 2.2).

Comment: hey android developers! Tell me is it that hard to achieve this? If so, I might rethink my plans...